# Issues with .animate() in Chrome (fine in Firefox and IE)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome, cross-browser, jquery-animate

I am simply trying to slide the main container (and everything within it) out of the way to show a navigation menu beneath when you click the navigate button. When you click it again, the container div moves back over top the navigation menu. It's UI that's gotten popular on mobile designs.

Anyway, I have it working just fine in Firefox and IE. Unfortunately, the same cannot be said for Chrome.

http://jsfiddle.net/aXsWz/28/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('div#navNavigate').click(function(){
        $('div#navNavigateHide').show()
        $('div#navNavigate').hide()
        $('div#container').animate({'left':'+=120'});
});  

$('div#navNavigateHide').click(function(){
        $('div#navNavigate').show()
        $('div#navNavigateHide').hide()
        $('div#container').animate({'left':'-=120'});
    });
});
```

So, the issue is that the "nav" and "container" divs aren't moving together.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update::

You have a fixed position rule on the navigation. If you change it to absolute, the animation will run properly:

```
#nav {
  background:#222222;
  width:240px;
  height:45px;
  margin:0 auto;
  position:absolute;  <-- This was previously "fixed"
  top:0;
  z-index:10000;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/aXsWz/30/

Take a look at this article to see the difference between fixed and absolute positioning: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

---

The problem is that you've nested your toggles inside of the container that gets moved around. If you refactor them to live outside of that container, it works just fine (although you can make quite a few improvements to this js pattern...).

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/aXsWz/29/

```
<div id='nav'>
    <div id='navNavigate'>
    </div>
    <div id='navNavigateHide'>
    </div>
</div>    

<div id='container'></div>
```

Comment: I want the nested toggles in the container because I want them to move with the container. In that example, the bar at the top stays stationary. I want it to move with the container. This works in Firefox. In Chrome though, "nav" div stays stationary like in your example. Then when you go to hide, the container moves back and the "nav" div actually makes the move over. So they move back and forth opposite one another, rather than together.

Comment: While that solves 1 of my problems (and the Fiddle), my actual code still does something strange in Chrome. I can't seem to replicate the issue, but let me try to explain it: So the container div, instead of just moving from it's current position. It jumps left (so that a good portion is off screen) and then animates right for the required distance. The problem is the jump. Not sure why it changes position before animating, but that's the issue. The "nav" and "container" do move together now so at least that's fixed (thank you!). And not sure how, but I did manage to fix the IE problem too.

Comment: I have edited my main post to replicate the new issue. The Fiddle actually works, but, as I mentioned, the issue is still present in my actual code (trying to replicate in Fiddle now).

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but you really should accept my answer and then make a new question for the issue you can't replicate... :) I'd be happy to take a look at the next issue in a new question once you can replicate the issue or provide a link to see the problem in action.

Comment: Will do. Not rude at all. I agree with you on that... have more or less reverted the main post to reflect my initial question so it's more useful to others too.

Comment: I'll be on the lookout for your new question!